# Accessing web server from LAN

Tags: wamp

I have wamp running on my laptop and trying to access page hosted on it from iDevices on my LAN. There are no errors but rather after some time it says server not responding 
I fixed httpd.conf file on Apache so it looks like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
ALlow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
Allow from 192.168. (This is line I added)
```

Comment: Have you allowed the HTTP port in the OS' firewall? Can you ping the web server from the other devices?

Comment: No and not sure how to do it. But this above worked 2 days ago. I didn't change anything and it doesn't work. I am just puzzled why it sopped working

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to really do anything other than guess several different possibilities. Most likely there's plenty of info on how to configure the firewall for HTTP access out there, you should go confirm it.  Which OS are you using exactly?

Comment: I am running wamp on windows 7.   I am trying to access page hosted on wamp using iPad air

Comment: Can you access the webserver from the same device where WAMP runs? What is the IP address of the device where it runs? How are you trying to connect to it from other devices?

Comment: Yes i can access it from my device that runs the server(laptop). Ip of the device that runs server is 192.168.1.5.  I al trying to access it from my iPad Air whose ip addres is 192.168.1.42

Comment: Seems definitely a firewall issue. Check your Windows 7 firewall for the LAN (as a first try you can completely disable it and check if that makes your devices able to access your WAMP server), if not, try disabling any antivirus.

Comment: Yes when i disabled firewall it worked